# VB.NET - Calling a method from a windows service

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have written a windows service which I am trying to call a public method from. I have referenced the .dll which contains the method and I am able to see it from within the code.

```
Public Sub DoNextExecution()
    SyncLock Me
        timer.Stop()

        EventLog.WriteEntry("Automated service started")
        MyClass.AutomatedService()
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Automated service finished")

        timer.Start()
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

The code runs to this point fine, but when executing the code 'MyClass.AutomatedService()' it hangs and does not proceed any further. AutomatedService is the method which I am trying to call. I have declared 'MyClass' as the following;

```
Dim MyClass As MyProject.MyClass
```

Is it possible to actually call a method in this way? or am I heading in the totally wrong direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `AutomatedService` attempt to display any UI, under any circumstances?

Comment: Are you sure AutomatedService is not simply still running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim MyClass As MyProject.MyClass`

MyClass will always `NULL` and you are trying to insansiate a method on the class where it's `null` causing an exception which will then jump over the `EventLog.WriteEntry("Automated service finished")` will not show because the exception will not be caught.